# MySQL - Joining effective dated data

Tags: mysql, join

I need to summarize data related to references with effective dates.

Let's imagine a salary schema with these tables

```
employee                                         work
+----+------+                                    +----+--------+------------+
| id | name |                                    | id | emp_id | date       |
+----+------+                                    +----+--------+------------+
|  1 | John |                                    |  1 |      1 | 2012-10-05 |
|  2 | Bob  |                                    |  2 |      1 | 2012-02-10 |
+----+------+                                    |  3 |      2 | 2012-09-03 |
                                                 |  4 |      1 | 2012-12-12 |
salary                                           |  5 |      1 | 2012-04-04 |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+      |  6 |      2 | 2012-06-09 |
| id | emp_id | daily_amount | start_date |      |  7 |      1 | 2012-07-24 |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+      +----+--------+------------+
|  1 |      1 |           10 | 2012-01-01 | 
|  2 |      1 |           15 | 2012-04-16 |
|  3 |      2 |           20 | 2012-05-25 |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
```

From 2012-01-01 **John** was paid 10 by day then from 2012-04-16, his pay is increased to 15.
**Bob** has been paid 20 since 2012-05-25

---

Now let's say I need to calculate the salary for both employees in 2012.
Here is my naive attempt:

```
SELECT
  emp.name AS "employee"
, SUM(sal.daily_amount) AS "amount"
FROM employee AS emp
JOIN work AS wrk ON (wrk.emp_id = emp.id)
JOIN salary AS sal ON (
  sal.emp_id = emp.id
  AND wrk.date >= sal.start_date
)
WHERE YEAR(wrk.date) = 2012
GROUP BY emp.id
;
```

Of course it does not give me what I want because it is not taking the MAX `start_date`

The question: What is the amount earned by Bob & John in 2012 ?

Comment: Fiddle at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d39d0

Comment: I would assume that this has been asked before, but I can't find a duplicate just now.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle, I didn't know SQLFiddle yet. I saw other posts asking about effective dates but most of the time on only one occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested the following on [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d39d0/8):

```
SELECT employee.name AS "employee",
       SUM(s1.daily_amount) AS "amount"
FROM work
  INNER JOIN salary s1
     ON work.emp_id = s1.emp_id
    AND work.date >= s1.start_date
  LEFT JOIN salary s2
     ON work.emp_id = s2.emp_id
    AND work.date >= s2.start_date
    AND s2.start_date > s1.start_date
  INNER JOIN employee
     ON work.emp_id = employee.id
WHERE s2.emp_id IS NULL
GROUP BY work.emp_id
```

The idea is to use the combination of `s1` and `s2` to look for the last date: `s1` is any salary definition prior to the day of work, while `s2` is `NULL` only if there is no later salary definition which would apply as well.

Comment: This seems quite smart. Thank you

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY, for a moment there was a different solution by [edze](http://stackoverflow.com/users/544992/edze) which used a subquery to add an end date to `salary`. Might provide better performance as the self-join of salary is computed only once and not for every row from `work`. Unfortunately he deleted his answer.

Comment: I saw his answer. So you are saying performance will be better with selfjoin than subquery right ?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY, we both do self joins, as we both use `salary` twice. But he does so in a subquery, without involving `work`, so his approach *might* be faster. In the end, it depends on how MySQL optimizes things, so your best bet is to benchmak things once performance becomes an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have a `salary table` with a start date but you need a end date too.
You can do this with a derived table:

```
  SELECT
    s_1.emp_id,
    s_1.daily_amount,
    s_1.start_date AS start,
    DATE_ADD(MIN(s_2.start_date), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS end
  FROM
    salary s_1
    LEFT JOIN salary s_2
      ON s_1.emp_id = s_2.emp_id AND s_1.start_date < s_2.start_date
  GROUP BY s_1.emp_id, s_1.start_date
```

At the end it would look like:

```
SELECT
  employee.name,
  SUM(s.daily_amount) AS amount
FROM
  employee
  JOIN work
    ON employee.id = work.emp_id
  JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        s_1.emp_id,
        s_1.daily_amount,
        s_1.start_date AS start,
        DATE_ADD(MIN(s_2.start_date), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS end
      FROM
        salary s_1
        LEFT JOIN salary s_2
          ON s_1.emp_id = s_2.emp_id AND s_1.start_date < s_2.start_date
      GROUP BY s_1.emp_id, s_1.start_date
    ) AS s
    ON employee.id = s.emp_id
    AND
    work.date >= s.start
    AND
    (work.date <= s.end OR s.end IS NULL)
GROUP BY employee.id
```

**EDIT** 
Without `DATE_ADD()`

```
SELECT
  employee.name,
  SUM(s.daily_amount) AS amount
FROM
  employee
  JOIN work
    ON employee.id = work.emp_id
  JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        s_1.emp_id,
        s_1.daily_amount,
        s_1.start_date AS start,
        MIN(s_2.start_date) AS end
      FROM
        salary s_1
        LEFT JOIN salary s_2
          ON s_1.emp_id = s_2.emp_id AND s_1.start_date < s_2.start_date
      GROUP BY s_1.emp_id, s_1.start_date
    ) AS s
    ON employee.id = s.emp_id
    AND
    work.date >= s.start
    AND
    (work.date < s.end OR s.end IS NULL)
GROUP BY employee.id
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I'm going to use @MvG's one for now because it's simpler, but I'll try yours if performance is concerned.

Comment: Tested at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d39d0/9. I guess this subquery approach might have better performance than my own answer. Any particular reason why you do the date arithmetic instead of simply `work.date < s.end`? As you can't use `BETWEEN … AND …` here, I'd consider that the easier solution.